# Ajax with PHP and XML, getElementsByTagName IE issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm having an issue with getElementsByTagName in IE (7 and 8).

I have an address lookup that returns each suggested address (as a string of XML) into a PHP session variable, which is then accessed using an AJAX function that returns the requested session variable.

Each session variable is set in step 1 of the ajax address lookup (I have tried with without the character encoding and with utf-8):

```
$_SESSION['addrHint_' . $k1] = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
$_SESSION['addrHint_' . $k1] .= '<Address>';
$_SESSION['addrHint_' . $k1] .= '<Postcode>' . $v1->Postcode . ' </Postcode>';
$_SESSION['addrHint_' . $k1] .= '<Line1>' . $v1->Line1 . ' </Line1>';
$_SESSION['addrHint_' . $k1] .= '<Line2>' . $v1->Line2 . ' </Line2>';
$_SESSION['addrHint_' . $k1] .= '<Line3>' . $v1->Line3 . ' </Line3>';
$_SESSION['addrHint_' . $k1] .= '</Address>';
```

And then retrieved in step 2:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print_r( $_SESSION['addrHint_'.$_REQUEST['addr']] );
```

In the AJAX js, when the state is ready, it performs amongst other similar lines of code, this:

```
var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;
var xmlRoot = xmlDoc.documentElement;
var postcode = xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName("Postcode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.forms[0]["address"+addr+"_Postcode"].value = postcode.substring(0, postcode.length-1);
```

(It does a similar thing for each line of the address.) The length-1 snippet is in there because I had to append a space to each element to stop an issue I was having when an element was null.

It works fine in Firefox, but not at all in IE. I have since been Googling and found a number of results among the first 5 pages but no solutions. I'd be most grateful if anyone could shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses below, I have since found the problem to be being caused when there is no, for example, line2 of the address, it breaks the script instead of skipping to the next line.  thought I had sorted this issue by appending spaces to each null value, so even if they were null it would have a value to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying your return values, maybe you should implement some error checking around the code that fetches your node values.

If you do a ton of chaining you can't check for nulls.
Instead of chaining like this:

```
xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName("Postcode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Why not add some error checking before hand?
Something like:

```
var postCodes = xmlRoot.getElementsByTagName("Postcode");
if( postCodes && postCodes[0] && postCodes[0].childNodes[0] ) {
    document.forms[0]["address"+addr+"_Postcode"].value = postCodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

That way you'll only attempt the assignment if there's no data there. Getting a blank input value where you expect it.

Now, all that chaining and if statement can get tiresome, so you can wrap that in a function if you like.

Feel free to check a working example here: http://jsbin.com/ahidu

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

print_r???

```
print_r( $_SESSION['addrHint_'.$_REQUEST['addr']] );
```

"$*SESSION['addrHint*'.$_REQUEST['addr']]" is not an array.

Comment: Yes, it's a string containing the xml code thus print_r() behaves like print/echo. Otherwise it wouldn't work in FF. print_r() might be confusing here, but it's not plain wrong ;-)

Comment: The print_r was leftover from when I was still returning an array, I had neglected to switch it back to an echo. Appreciate the explanations regarding its proper usage though.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IE developer tools (IE8: built-in, IE7: [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en)) to debug the javascript.
You might also want to add some [console debug code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(VS.85).aspx#consolelogging) e.g. to track the readystate.
On the server-side set php's error_reporting to E_ALL and keep an eye on the webserver's error.log (where the php messages will show up)

Comment: That developer toolbar is incredibly handy! I had no idea it existed, thanks for the heads up.